# Как через цикл for of вывести с двумерный массива в console.log?

Tags: javascript, функции, for

На первом этапе, for of срабатывает и выводит элементы массива:

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]];

for( i of arr){
    console.log(i);
}
```

```
(5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(3) [6, 7, 8]
(2) [9, 10]
```

Я дописал цикл :

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]];

for( i of arr){
    for (i of j) {
        console.log(j);
    }
}
```

но ожидаемого результата: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 нету...

Помогите пожалуйста дописать цикл

Comment: `for (i of j)` — вы пытаетесь пройтись циклом по несуществующей переменной `j`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]];

for (let i of arr) {
  for (let j of i) {
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

или

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]];
let result = [];
for (let i of arr) {
  for (let j of i) {
    result.push(j);
  }
}
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

или

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]];
console.log(arr.flat().join(' '));
```